# Blazor Server Side and dynamic table generation

Tags: html, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to build a dynamic table with Blazor, but I encounter an issue with DOM validation.

I'm using Bootstrap for layout to have access to `row` and `col` css classes. I have a list of item, with a dynamic size (can be 0, 3 or 10, even 100), and I want to display those item within a card, 3 per row.

I did the following thing :

```
        <div class="row profile-row" style="margin-left:10px">
            @for (int i = 0; i < myObjectList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i % 3 == 0 && i != 0)
                {
                    @((MarkupString)("</div><div class='row profile-row' style='margin-left:10px'>"))
                }
                <div class="col-4">
                    <MyObjectComponent item="myObjectList[i]"></MyObjectComponent>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
```

This seems to be great, but it looks like when doing MarkupString, Blazor ensure valid HTML is produce. So my firt block of ending div is not written and the following div is immediatelly closed, which I don't want.

If I don't use MarkupString, I go a compilation error because of invalid HTML in my syntax. Any ideas how to do so ?

Comment: can you tell me what is in the MarkupString (examples would be helpful) and where it is coming from ? also what is the html you are trying to get to.

Comment: MarkupString is a struct to output string as HTML in Razor pages. The HTML would be to have <div class="row">{<div class="col-4"></div>3 times}</div> for each block of 3 objects within my list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want a grid with something in a div of class col-4 that will give you 3 cols per  row you do not need to manage the rows as bootstrap will do that for you, here is the code  using image instead of object but the principle is still the same.

```
<h1>Testing Table</h1>
<div class="row profile-row" style="margin-left:10px">
            @foreach(var image in Images)
            {
                <div class="col-4">
                     <img src="@image" style="width:100%; padding-bottom:10px" />
                </div>
            }
        </div>

@code {


List<String> Images = new List<String>() {
        "https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/pineapple-headphones-wooden-table-horizontal-front-black-background-62166845.jpg",
         "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558981852-426c6c22a060?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" ,
         "https://images.pexels.com/photos/853168/pexels-photo-853168.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" ,
         "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT-sZlG6VgOM5DgG6RToxO2PPvZFml3y-L2WGJjxLIfVU4wGAN0yA&s" ,
         "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524293581917-878a6d017c71?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" ,
         "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504575958497-ccdd586c2997?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1354&q=80" ,
         "https://images.pexels.com/photos/853168/pexels-photo-853168.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" ,
         "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT-sZlG6VgOM5DgG6RToxO2PPvZFml3y-L2WGJjxLIfVU4wGAN0yA&s" ,
         "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531219432768-9f540ce91ef3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" ,
         "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT-sZlG6VgOM5DgG6RToxO2PPvZFml3y-L2WGJjxLIfVU4wGAN0yA&s" ,
         "https://images.pexels.com/photos/853168/pexels-photo-853168.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" ,
         "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558981852-426c6c22a060?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" ,
         "https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/pineapple-headphones-wooden-table-horizontal-front-black-background-62166845.jpg" ,
         "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558981852-426c6c22a060?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80" ,
         "https://images.pexels.com/photos/853168/pexels-photo-853168.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" ,
         "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT-sZlG6VgOM5DgG6RToxO2PPvZFml3y-L2WGJjxLIfVU4wGAN0yA&s" ,
         "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524293581917-878a6d017c71?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" ,
         "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504575958497-ccdd586c2997?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1354&q=80" ,
         "https://images.pexels.com/photos/853168/pexels-photo-853168.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" ,
         "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT-sZlG6VgOM5DgG6RToxO2PPvZFml3y-L2WGJjxLIfVU4wGAN0yA&s" ,
         "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531219432768-9f540ce91ef3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" ,
         "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT-sZlG6VgOM5DgG6RToxO2PPvZFml3y-L2WGJjxLIfVU4wGAN0yA&s" ,
         "https://images.pexels.com/photos/853168/pexels-photo-853168.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" ,
         "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558981852-426c6c22a060?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80"
    };
}
```

I have put this on blazor fiddle so you can see the output https://blazorfiddle.com/s/1ptaljre

Answer (score 2):

All you need is a better algorithm to make rows-of-3. You could leave that to CSS (and be adaptable to screen size) but in C#:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < myObjectList.Count; i += 3)
{
  <div class="row profile-row" style="margin-left:10px">

  @for(int j = i; (j < i+3) && (j < myObjectList.Count); j++)
  {
       <div class="col-4">
         <MyObjectComponent item="myObjectList[j]"></MyObjectComponent>
       </div>
  }
  </div>
}
```